# How to change the class of a column in a list of a list from character to numeric in r?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

The codes for producing sample dataset and converting from character to numeric is as below:

```
ff = data.frame(a = c('1','2','3'),b = 1:3, c = 5:7)
#data.frame is a type of list.

fff = list(ff,ff,ff,ff)

k = fff %>% map(~map(.x,function(x){x['a'] %<>% as.numeric
  return(x)}))
```

However, the result is something like this...:
There are 3 lists appear in each of the nested list ==> 3*3 = 9, which is very strange.
I think the result should have 3 lists in a nested list.==> 3*1 = 3

what I want is to convert every `a` in each dataframe to be numeric.

```
> k
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
              a 
"1" "2" "3"  NA 

[[1]]$b
          a 
 1  2  3 NA 

[[1]]$c
          a 
 5  6  7 NA 


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
              a 
"1" "2" "3"  NA 

[[2]]$b
          a 
 1  2  3 NA 

[[2]]$c
          a 
 5  6  7 NA 


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
              a 
"1" "2" "3"  NA 

[[3]]$b
          a 
 1  2  3 NA 

[[3]]$c
          a 
 5  6  7 NA 


[[4]]
[[4]]$a
              a 
"1" "2" "3"  NA 

[[4]]$b
          a 
 1  2  3 NA 

[[4]]$c
          a 
 5  6  7 NA
```

I cannot understand why I cannot convert `a` into numeric...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, with `mutate`:

```r
fff %>% 
  map(~ mutate(.x, a = as.numeric(a)))
```

Or, more base R style:

```r
fff %>% 
  map(\(x) {x$a <- as.numeric(x$a); x})
```

---

You should use `map` only once, because you don't have a nested list. With the first `map`, you access to each dataframe, and then you can convert to numeric. With a second `map`, you are accessing the columns of each data frame (which you don't want).

With two `map`s, it's also preferable to use `\` or `function` rather than `~` because it becomes confusing to use `.x` and `x` for different objects. In your question, `.x` is the dataframe, while `x` are columns of it.

Comment: Would you mind to explain why it will have 3 lists inside the nested lists? (3*3)

Comment: Data.frame is a type of list, but list is not a type of data.frame...?

Comment: Actually yes, exactly.

Comment: If you consider list in the large sense, you do have a nested list. But with `map` you need to know at which level to do the operation. The easiest would be to do it at the level of the dataframe, by changing a column. With one `map`, you go down by one level, and you don't need to go further down with another map, since you can change a column at the level of the dataframe

Comment: Since I wrongly misclassify data.frames in the list are also lists, so I think I need to use nested `map` to solve the problem. That is the point I do'not understand: whether data.frame is a list or not.

Comment: Dataframes are lists. Lists are higher-order type of object and less restrictive than dataframes. Dfs contains columns that are usually vectors, lists contains anything (including other lists, dfs...). So if you do two `map`s, you will apply the function to each column. You want to select one column among all of them and convert to numeric. This is possible only at the level of the dataframe.